# Measuring Django Command duration with NewRelic

Tags: django, newrelic

I have a set of Django commands that do some complex operations, and I'd like to begin tracking the duration of how long they take, in order to monitor their performance over time.

I've struggled to figure out how to instrument newrelic to capture the duration. I've tried everything from 'assuming' the standard django newrelic agent will magically capture it, to try to instrument them myself as a custom event, all with varying degrees of success.

What is the best way to do this, and does newrelic provide something to facilitate this? The docs were very lacking for this kind of scenario.

Additionally, I would consider these as background_tasks - what is the background_task field in newrelic used for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At New Relic we do have a prototype for some changes we are considering making to the Python agent which will add support for monitoring nominated Django admin commands. We are still working through some details of those changes but it is possible it will make it in to one of the upcoming releases over the next couple of months.

In the interim, what you can do is add something like the following to your agent configuration file:

```
[newrelic:django-manage]
app_name = Python Application (Django Management Commands)
startup_timeout = 10.0

[background-task:django-manage-syncdb]
enabled = true
function = django.core.management.commands.syncdb:Command.handle_noargs
name = syncdb
group = Django
```

You would then run the Django manage.py script as:

```
NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini
NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT=django-manage

export NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE
export NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT

newrelic-admin run-python manage.py syncdb
```

When the data is then reported into our UI, it will appear under 'Type -> Other transactions -> Django' in the 'Transactions' tab for the specified application.

[image]

The 'newrelic:django-manage' section is an environment section that allows you to override the 'app_name' setting defining which application in our UI the data should be reported to. The 'NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT' variable says that the environment section should be used as overrides for the default 'newrelic' section'.

Even if you do not override 'app_name' and have it inherit the value from the default 'newrelic' section, you still must set the 'startup_timeout' setting. This is necessary as under normal circumstances the agent will only lazily register itself in the background when the first web request is being handled by a web application. Having registration being done lazily will though cause a problem when tracking Django management commands as a background task. This is because there is only the one function call to be monitored, and not waiting for agent registration to occur will result in no data being captured. Setting a non zero value for the startup timeout therefore says to wait for registration to occur.

If for some reason agent registration takes too long, the timeout will expire after the specified time and the management command allowed to proceed anyway. Either way, the need to wait means that there will be a delay in actually starting the management command. This should be kept in mind if the management command needs to be run as quickly as possible.

If necessary, a 'shutdown_timeout' can also be specified if the uploading of data captured by the agent is consistently taking longer than the default 2.5 seconds and therefore not always being reported.

As to the 'background-task' section, it defines the specific function which should be monitored and reported as a background task. In this case we are targeting the particular function implementing the Django 'syncdb' command.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did what you said (but made some slight tweaks since my command has a dash, such as test-foo), but I cant seem to find where the data would be in the dashboard. I click on applications, then click on my app (which takes me to monitoring), then I click on transactions. I cant seem to find 'other transactions' or django. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have added a screen shot. Use the 'Type' drop down top left in the tab to get to 'Other transactions -> Django'.

Comment: Unfortunately, my dashboard does not look like yours, and I cant seem to find it. Here's a snippit of how mine looks - http://imgur.com/P6qDHUc - perhaps it is because mine is from Heroku? Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try clearing the browser cache for items related to New Relic sites. That or try a different browser. The change to show both web transactions and background tasks under the Transactions tab was a recent change and some people have not seeing it displayed properly because of the browser cache retaining old CSS etc. If that doesn't help lodge a support ticket at New Relic and we can confirm whether the agent is actually connecting from your script. Remember to make sure that the startup timeout is specified as explained and that if in a separate environment section that is selected.